# How to handle AccessViolationException in C# with MS Access 2010

Tags: c#

I am using C# Windows Application as front end and MS Access 2010 as back end.

I am getting `Access Violation Error` when executing the below code:

```
private void cmbBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (cmbBox.SelectedItem != null) { 
    ProcessTreeData(cmbBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), treePane); 
  } 
} 

public void ProcessTreeData(string projectName, TreeView view) { 
  string query = "select ID, VisibleName from Project where InternalName ='" + projectName + "'"; MessageBox.Show(query); 
  DataTable project_tble = new DataTable(); 
  project_tble = dbCon.GetValuesFromDatabaseInTable(query);
  ...
}
```

Issues occurs when executing the line `project_tble = dbCon.GetValuesFromDatabaseInTable(query);`

I am getting this error consistently in MS Access 2010 as database and not in MS Access 2007 as database

Where is the problem actually?

Is there any compatibility issue with Windows 07 and MS Access 2010?

because error is not occurred with
`MS Access 2007` in `Windows 07` and `MS Access 2010` in `Window XP`

Kindly help me in this... Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there any inner exceptions?  Are you connecting via OleDB?  In addition is there any particular reason you're using Access?

Comment: Access Violation Error, I have tried in Windows XP PC and I don't get any issue, they are also using the same MS Access 2010 Database, But in Windows 07 I get.

Comment: Yes I am connecting via OLEDB, yes customer needs the application to be developed in MS Access 2010 or higher...

Comment: The problem occurs, when I click on the button, which executes the database Query...

Comment: Issue occurs when this line of code executes,             project_tble = dbCon.GetValuesFromDatabaseInTable(query);

Comment: private void cmbBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (cmbBox.SelectedItem != null)
{
ProcessTreeData(cmbBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), treePane);
}
}
 
public void ProcessTreeData(string projectName, TreeView view)
{
string query = "select ID, VisibleName from Project where InternalName ='" + projectName + "'";
MessageBox.Show(query);
\\ Issues occurs when below line code executes...
 
DataTable project_tble = new DataTable();
project_tble = dbCon.GetValuesFromDatabaseInTable(query);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Access Viloation Issue has been resolved, by using Timer Control.
All the function call in the form load that we have implemented, have been moved to Timer Control event.
So, once the form is loaded, after 1 sec delay all the functions will be called in the Timer Control.